# sqlsrv drivers slow in codeigniter?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have installed the latest version of CI 2.1.3

Now after running a query, I am getting a very slow response time for something very simple such as:

```
function Bash(){


    $sql = “SELECT * FROM Contacts”;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

after querying a remote database. (Sql server 2008)

When I run this same query in a simple PHP script against the same remote database. I get results instantly.

a) Has anyone else experienced this problem with the sqlsrv drivers in codeigniter?

If so, how did you solve it?

Here is my connection string:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx,1433";
$db['default']['username'] = "xx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxxx-xx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxxxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "sqlsrv";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

UPDATE:

I have found the following from running the profiler.

DATABASE:  database   QUERIES: 1  (Hide)
0.0659    select * from Contacts

Loading Time: Base Classes   0.0428
Controller Execution Time ( Welcome / AzureBash )   58.2173
Total Execution Time   58.2602

It seems as though the query is executing in 0.06 secs but the controller is taking a minute to load.

No idea why this is happening.

**Solution**

The active records interface for the latest SQLSRV drivers are buggy.

So, download and overwrite the existing interface with these (overwrite your sqlsrv folder in the database folder in CI):

http://www.kaweb.co.uk/blog/mssql-server-2005-and-codeigniter/

Note: These have been tested with SQL Azure and works.

$query->num_rows(); does not work with these drivers, so I suggest you use count instead. Or create your own wrapper.

In addition date is now a date object type in your result set.

I hope this helps.

**Solution 2**

If for whatever reason you find a bug that makes this completely unusable.  Revert back to the sqlsrv interface originally provided. You will find what is causing the problem is the way the original interface are executing the query, thus, create a database helper class; use $sql = $this->db->last_query(); to get the query you was about to execute and then within the database_helper class execute it yourself:

```
function MakeDbCall ($sql)
{
$serverName = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx,1433"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx","ConnectionPooling" => "1");



 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $result_array[] = $row;
}

return $result_array;

}
```

Create one for row_array.

You should be able to call this function directly, from anywhere in your app. Whilst taking advantage of the way active_records constructs your query.

Not an ideal solution, but until codeigniter sort their SQLSRV class, there is not a lot we can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

The active records interface for the latest SQLSRV drivers are buggy.

So, download and overwrite the existing interface with these (overwrite your sqlsrv folder in the database folder in CI):

http://www.kaweb.co.uk/blog/mssql-server-2005-and-codeigniter/

Note: These have been tested with SQL Azure and works.

$query->num_rows(); does not work with these drivers, so I suggest you use count instead. Or create your own wrapper.

In addition date is now a date object type in your result set.

**Solution 2**

If for whatever reason you find a bug that makes this completely unusable.   Revert back to the sqlsrv interface originally provided. You will find what is causing the problem is the way the original interface are executing the query, thus, create a database helper class; use $sql = $this->db->last_query(); to get the query you was about to execute and then within the database_helper class execute it yourself:

```
function MakeDbCall ($sql)
{
$serverName = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx,1433"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx","ConnectionPooling" => "1");



 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $result_array[] = $row;
}

return $result_array;

}
```

Create one for row_array.

You should be able to call this function directly, from anywhere in your app. Whilst taking advantage of the way active_records constructs your query.

Not an ideal solution, but until codeigniter sort their SQLSRV class, there is not a lot we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer to this after the answer has already been accepted because I found a different solution. I was having the same problem ... looping through the result set was very very slow. i opened system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php and found the connection function. i noticed that is was using the SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC option. i changed this to SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED and my slowness problems went away. See documentation for this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160(v=sql.105).aspx

I honestly have no idea what the sql server driver for php is doing, however, given the speed up, etc i can guess that the driver might be using a cursor by default. this seems like an awful idea. i also am assuming that by choosing client_buffered the data for the query would b e read without a cursor and accessed in memory on the client as if it were a cursor. If this is the case, bad things might happen if you try to execute a query that has many many rows to read. Perhaps another option (SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD?) can be used to read data without a cursor - but i'm sure the methods used to access the query will be more limited (e.g. not using result_array())

-Don

Comment: This worked well enough for me. Not sure what the repercussions of this might be.

Comment: It appears that the driver will quickly (without a cursor) loop through all records and store them in a memory array. This will be just fine until you have a query that returns thousands of rows. In that case, it might be best to skip the code igniter driver wrappers and call the sqlsrv api directly. That way you can loop through  results without storing all of the data in memory and without using a cursor.

Comment: Hi Don, I solved the problem by finding a better driver adapter: http://www.kaweb.co.uk/blog/mssql-server-2005-and-codeigniter/. I would suggest not calling the sqlsrv api directly, because it will only lead to complications down the line (say you decide to switch to another driver that has a different syntax,without a wrapper, you will spend your time rewriting your code.). This has been tested on azure and works fine. I am aware it is a bit slow if you try to connect to a web server from your local machine, but I guess that is a latency issue. Rather than a driver issue. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is your connection string?  You can specify the "network protocol" explicitly, which somtimes can affect speed.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/articles/show/define-sql-server-network-protocol

"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=pubs;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

By specifying the IP address, the port number (1433) and the Network Library, you are providing a very granular connection string.
Your details may vary of course.

Alot of times, you don't need this.  But I've been on a few client trips where this was the magic dust.

Comment: It doesn't look like they provided a hook for the network_library.   :<   Maybe try some updated drivers.   http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205186/#966443      http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098   But basically, I have no idea......just trying to help.

Comment: You can "answer your own question" and mark it as "the answer", FYI.  Not a "go to" move, but still, if you found the answer, then do it.  And also, it'll be marked as "resolved" by the website, so people won't keep seeing it as an unanswered quesiton.  . PS  And you can mark any answer here as "helpful".  (Just saying).

Comment: The Up and Down arrow, click the "Up" arrow.  Each post will have a corresponding Up and Down arrow.  (Upper left from each post).

Comment: I just up-voted your answer.  On your answer there should be a big "check" icon, that you can mark it as "The Best Solution".  I can't remember, you might have to wait a few days to be able to select your own answer as "The Best Solution" to keep people from artificially inflating their own reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to turn db_debug to FALSE which should save time debugging the database.

Also, would suggest to turn cache_on to FALSE and specify cachedir and use `$this->db->cache_on();` for queries that are less dynamic, i.e. does not change frequently.

Comment: Made an amendment, see above. That didnt work by the way, but thanks.

Comment: Yep, see my original post for the amendment.

Answer (score 1):

For speed up fetch up to 3 times please use `"MultipleActiveResultSets"=>'0'` in your `sqlsrv_connect` connection options.

Ex:

```php
    $db = sqlsrv_connect(
        '127.0.0.1', 
        array(
            'Database'=>'dbname',
            'UID'=> 'sa',
            'PWD'=> 'pass',
            "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8",
            "ConnectionPooling" => "1",
            "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>'0'  # <--- Relevant setting
        )
    );
```

Comment: Note: This will disable iteration over multiple query results. Instead app will loose access to results of previous query when new query is issued to DB. In such a case, fetch **all** relevant rows before issuing next query.