# Result_array sqlsrv very slow in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-2

See here:

[sqlsrv drivers slow in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887986/sqlsrv-drivers-slow-in-codeigniter)

I am finding that when connecting to a remote sql server database. It is EXTREMELY slow for even SELECT *. I know this is not a problem with sqlsrv itself, because after writing a bash script which connects to the remote database using raw sqlsrv syntax it works instantly. This leads me to believe that this is an active records problem.

When I write the same script using the active records class to do a SELECT * From table. I have found that query->result_array(); is extremely slow.

I have no idea why this is happening.

To resolve this issue I've tried sqlsrv_fetch_assoc instead of result_array, but the time to return a result set is slow.

Has anyone else experienced this and resolved this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is your DB server on localhost? Test absolutely the same query how time will take on both Codeigniter and on your sql server manager + you can make 1 test PHP file to connect to your server and test the same query without using CI

Comment: The DB sever is on a web host elseware. I connect via the IP, port in DB config settings. When running this against localhost, its fine. However when running this against any web host (I've tried 2 so far) everything is slow. Query time seems to be fast in both circumstances, it is just that bizarrely on a remote server, the controller takes a long time to load based on the CI profiler.

Comment: Yep did that, it was instant.

Comment: show your DB settings (remove the username/pass/ip)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887986/sqlsrv-drivers-slow-in-codeigniter/15889225?noredirect=1#comment22624805_15889225 See here

Comment: set to false db_debug and cache to check if there is difference

Comment: Done so , no difference. See thread provided an update. Seems like my controller is taking 60 seconds to load :(

Comment: Why did you make a second question with the exact same problem?

Comment: solved the problem see the other thread. Thanks for your help.